# Cannot centralize div on bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to centralize the div "Status" using css. Already tryied to use vertical-align: middle, display: flex, align-item: center and nothing works. Can someone help me? it seens like the height of the div remains the same so I can't centralize it since it's content fills it's exactly entire space.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Row, Col } from 'reactstrap'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Status from './Status'

export default ({ temporadas = [], temporadaSelecionada = {}, onChange = () => {} }) => {
  return (
    <StyledContainer>
      <Row>
        <Col md={12}>
          {temporadas.map(temporada => {
            return (
              <StyledCard selected={temporadaSelecionada.codigo === temporada.codigo}
                onClick={() => onChange(temporada)}>
                <Status className='pull-right' style={{ marginRight: '-8px' }} ativa={temporada.status === 'A'} />
                {/* <StyledIcon className={temporadaSelecionada.codigo === temporada.codigo ? 'fa fa-fw fa-minus' : 'fa fa-fw fa-plus'} /> */}
                <StyledText alt={temporada.descricao} title={temporada.descricao}>{temporada.descricao || '-'}</StyledText>
              </StyledCard>
            )
          })}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </StyledContainer>
  )
}


const StyledContainer = styled.div`
  margin-bottom: 10px;
`

const StyledCard = styled.div`
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 16px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #DADFEA;
  background-color: #F4F7FA;
  font-size: 100%

  &:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: -1px;
  }

  &:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  }

  ${({ selected }) => selected && `
    border-left: 5px solid #C5CBD9;
    padding-left: 12px;
  `}
`

const StyledText = styled.span`
  margin: 0;
`

const StyledIcon = styled.i`
  font-size: 10px;
`
```

The div "Status" is imported from another file and it behaves like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

export default ({ ativa, label, ...props }) => {
  if (ativa) {
    return (
      <div {...props}>
        <StyledText>
          <StyledLabel>{label}</StyledLabel>
          <i class='fa fa-fw fa-circle text-success' />
          <span>Ativa</span>
        </StyledText>
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <div {...props}>
        <StyledText>
          <StyledLabel>{label}</StyledLabel>
          <i class='fa fa-fw fa-circle text-danger' />
          <span>Inativa</span>
        </StyledText>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const StyledText = styled.small`
  text-transform: none;
`

const StyledLabel = styled.span`
  color: #79919D;
`
```

I want to put that div in the vertical-center of the row it is contained in. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you considered using `display` of `flex` on `StyledCard` with justify and align

Comment: Yes. It centered it horizontally. What I want to do is to center it vertically

Comment: You can visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66747214/cannot-centralize-div-on-bootstrap/66747423#66747423 and if you find useful please upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way.

```
<div className=" centeredDiv">
<status></status>
<div>

 .centeredDiv{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: you can convert the css to styled component as per your requirements

Comment: this, acctually, center it horizontally. What I want to do is to center it vertically

Comment: It solved my problem. I wasn't find the father to put this codeline..